# Failed to restore the NuGet packages: Error: MSBuild tools not found

Tags: windows, visual-studio, react-native

I am trying to get `React Native For Windows` working, but I am having tough times installing the required dependencies. I have installed Visual Studio and installed the required dependencies as well

[image]

I am gettign following error `Failed to restore the NuGet packages: Error: MSBuild tools not found. Make sure all required components have been installed (e.g. v141 support)` when i run

```
 npx react-native run-windows
```

I have found issue regarding this https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/3263 but the solution  does not work for me
 I have installed everything related to this

I have nodejs installed in my PC.

I am using the recommended version of React Native

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the Desktop development workload selected in the VS installer. See this:
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl57y.png)

Comment: I had it selected, but also fails for me.